# Windows 8 error: prevented an unauthorized app from running

Tags: c#, .net, windows, visual-studio-2010, dll

My application created in windows visual studio 2010 runs 100% FINE in windows 7 and vista. But, wen it comes to windows 8, it says "`Windows SmartScreen prevented an unauthorized app from running`". It is a speech recognition software so it uses `speech.dll`

Why this error is happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, The answer is bit funny. There is a "Run Anyway" button in the dialog, which is not visible until you click the down arrow.